# Provide a counter example to (sets)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets.  If $A\times C=B\times C$, then $A=B$. Is there any way to ensure that $A$ does not equal $B$ when this happens (hence counter example?  Thus far, I've not been able to think of one.  I'm thinking if they all have the same number of elements, it really won't work.  Not sure how else I can look at this one.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming $A,B,C$ are nonempty?

Comment: as it was presented to me, they didn't specify that one so that would be fair game.

Comment: In that case take $C = \emptyset$ with $A \neq B$ any nonempty sets of your choice. That is a counter example.

Comment: but if we have AxC=BxC yet C is empty, then wouldn't we still have the "problem" of A still being equal to B?

Comment: Not if at least one of $A$, $B$ is nonempty and $A \neq B$. For  example, take $A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}, C = \emptyset$

Comment: so we could have C={}, then A={1} B={2}?

Comment: oops sorry i didn't refresh in time

Comment: Haha no problem. But you tell me: Is it true in this example that $A \neq B$, and also that $A \times C = B \times C$? If that is true... seems like we have found a counterexample

Comment: The first part definitely I see.  A definitely does NOT equal B.  But I'm still not seeing how we are able to say AxC=BxC

Comment: I see. You would need to know that $A\times \emptyset = \emptyset$. You could try to prove it? Intuitively it should be true. $A\times C$ should be all the ordered pairs of the form $(a,c)$ where $a\in A, c\in C$. However no such $c$ exists so no ordered pairs exist. A collection of nothing is empty, so $A\times \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh...man... ok.  So when you cross AxC, it doesn't give you: (1,{})?  It just makes that whole thing the empty set.  I question this book at times like these haha.

Comment: Correct. $\{\}$ is not a coordinate, so it doesn't make sense to consider $(1,\{\})$.

Comment: Ah good call.  yeah graph something that doesn't exist lol

Comment: Thanks very much for filling in that rather critical piece of information

Comment: Not a problem! Connecting new stuff back to things you understand can be a good way to understand the new stuff. So connecting this problem to the $x$-$y$ plane is a good idea. The point $(1,\{\})$ would be like saying "The point where $x = 1$ and $y$ does not have a value." Well, every point on the $x$-$y$ plane has a $y$ coordinate value, so the point $(1,\{\})$ cannot exist.

Comment: Imagine $A$ is a set of boys, and $B$ is a set of girls, and $A \times B$ is the set of boy-girl couples that could conceivably be dancing on the dance floor (perhaps it's a rule that only boy-girl pairings are allowed). Who's dancing if no girls show up?

Comment: No grooving in that case haha.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A\ne B$ then either $A$ has some member that is not a member of $B$ or $B$ has some member that is not a member of $A$. Suppose the former: $x\in A\setminus B$.  Then take any member $y$ of $C$ and get a pair $(x,y)$ that is a member of $A\times C$ but not of $B\times C$ so $A\times C\ne B\times C$, **EXCEPT** that you'll notice that I said "take any member $y$ of $C$", and that can be done if, but only if, $C$ is not empty.

Hence $A\times\varnothing=B\times\varnothing$ even if $A\ne B$, but if $C\ne\varnothing$ then $A\times C=B\times C$ only if $A=B$.